# Cannot assign ws response to $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with setting result when i get a ws message.
I have a controller, when i click some button, it invokes `getStops` func.

In this func (`getStops`) i use ws connection, when i get message
(at `ws.onmessage`) i need to get
`tramState['stop_id']` and assing it to `$scope.current_stop`.

And then in `ul` list, appropriate `li` should become active.
But it doesn't happen, `$scope.current_stop` is always `null`.

Where is the problem? Thanks.

```
angular.module('tramApp').
    controller('tramController', ['$scope', 'tramAPIService', function($scope, tramAPIService) {
        $scope.trams = [];
        $scope.stops = [];
        $scope.active_tram = null;
        $scope.current_stop = null;

    $scope.getStops = function (tram_id) {
        tramAPIService.getStops(tram_id)
            .then(stops => $scope.stops = stops);

        $scope.active_tram = tram_id;

        const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://192.168.0.103:8080/tram_ws/?tram_id=${tram_id}`);

        ws.onmessage = (message) => {
            let tramState = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(message.data));
            $scope.current_stop = (tramState['stop_id'] !== "None") ? Number(tramState['stop_id']) : null;
            console.log(tramState);
        };
    };

    tramAPIService.getTrams()
        .then(trams => $scope.trams = trams);

}]);  


<ul class="list-group">
      <li
          class="list-group-item"
          ng-repeat="s in stops"
          ng-class="{'active': s.stop_id === current_stop}">
          {{ s.stop_id }}, {{ s.stop_name }}
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are updating angular `$scope` varaible from outside AngularJS context, where angularjs isn't aware about those changes and hence the changes doesn't reflect in the UI. The process of updating binding w.r.t it `$scope` is called as digest cycle system. In this case you have to trigger this process manually to see updates on the screen.

You can trigger this process by two way

1. By calling `$apply` method on `$scope`
2. Or `$timeout` and `$applyAsync` method. (**Preferred way**)

   ```
   ws.onmessage = (message) => {
       let tramState = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(message.data));
       $scope.$applyAsync(function(){
          $scope.current_stop = (tramState['stop_id'] !== "None") ? Number(tramState['stop_id']) : null;
       });
   };
   ```

Comment: Can i ask you? I've added some code after $applyAsync call.  

 `if (stops.indexOf($scope.current_stop) === -1)  

                    tramAPIService.getStops(tram_id)  

                        .then(stops => $scope.stops = stops);`  

How it works without $applyAsync?

Comment: It works because you made an ajaxcall using `getStops` method, which must be using `$http` API service of Angular, which call digest cycle after completion ajax, so that's why no need to run digest cycle manually. Refer [this slide](https://slides.com/pankajparkar/boost-angular-application-performance#/14), it dictate when Angular fire digest cycle.

Comment: Yeah `getStops` uses `$http`, i got it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @AlexNemet check the slide link from one my presentation. I hope it would help you to understand, when digest cycle fires and when not.